# my tablet view keeps overriding my desktop view, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

## ---------- @media (min-width: 991px) and (max-width:768px){} .container, .container1, .container2 .container3{ float: left; } .container1{ width: 50%; } .container2{ width: 50%; } .container3{ width: 100%; } /*****Desktop *****/ @media (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 992px){} .container, .container1, .container2 .container3{ float: left; } .container1{ width: 33.33%; } .container2{ width: 33.33%; } .container3{ width: 33.33%; }

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted your code and formatted it. The way it is posted above, it looks like your styling is actually sitting outside of your media query curly braces. You need to move your styling INSIDE of the curly braces that begin immediately after your query like below:

```
@media (min-width: 991px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container,
    .container1,
    .container2 .container3 {
      float: left;
    }
    .container1 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .container2 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .container3 {
      width: 100%;
}

} /*****Desktop *****/
@media (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .container,
    .container1,
    .container2 .container3 {
      float: left;
    }
    .container1 {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
    .container2 {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
    .container3 {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
}
```

This may fix your issue.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that both the media queries are empty. This is the given CSS (with just some linefeeds added to give a bit more clarity):

```
 @media (min-width: 991px) and (max-width:768px){}
    
     .container, .container1, .container2 .container3{ float: left; }
    
     .container1{ width: 50%; } .container2{ width: 50%; }
    
     .container3{ width: 100%; } 
    
    /*****Desktop *****/ @media (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 992px){} 
    
    .container, .container1, .container2 .container3{ float: left; }
    
     .container1{ width: 33.33%; } .container2{ width: 33.33%; } .container3{ width: 33.33%; }
```

If this is indeed the CSS that is being used, then what is described as 'Desktop' will win as it comes last in the list. So you will see container1, container2 and container3 each having 33.33% width of whatever their containing element is.

BUT this does not mean that all 3 will be on the same line, assuming that is the intention, because each (by default at least, and we are not told whether this has been changed elsewhere) may have some margin and padding set so it's quite likely just 2 will appear on the first row and the third will be beneath that. This could be mistaken for the 'tablet' view as just 2 elements are next to each other.

Now suppose the media queries were laid out (as @MockerNicholas has suggested) with the closing bracket positioned so that the CSS settings are included in each media query:

```
 @media (min-width: 991px) and (max-width:768px){
    
     .container, .container1, .container2 .container3{ float: left; }
    
     .container1{ width: 50%; } .container2{ width: 50%; }
    
     .container3{ width: 100%; }
   }
    
    /*****Desktop *****/
    @media (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 992px){ 
    
    .container, .container1, .container2 .container3{ float: left; }
    
     .container1{ width: 33.33%; } .container2{ width: 33.33%; } .container3{ width: 
     33.33%; }
     }
```

Now let's look at the media queries. The first one says 'if the width is at least 991px and if your width is less than 768px apply the following settings'. But this can never be true. You can't have both conditions satisfied at once. The same is true for the second media query.

My guess is that the brackets were incorrectly placed in the CSS given in the quesiton AND that the conditions have been stated the wrong way round.

You may like to read up about media queries, their formatting and how they work for example at [MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Amazing, i knew something was wrong with the brackets and the media queries